# Closing connections in java application which uses singleton frames

Tags: java, swing, singleton, database-connection

I am creating a java application using SwingGUI. I have used singleton classes for frames (to avoid creation of multiple frames). Also, the class uses database connectivity. Now, at the start of the application (HomeScreen), I have created and initialised the DB connection and close it when the app is closed. However, the DB statement is created privately in classes (the class is like a form to entry info) everytime I need to access the DB. After I use the statement for DB manipulation, I close it as well as the form. Now when I reopen the form (without restarting the app), and try to enter values in the form, I am shown the error:

```
Error executing insert query  !!!
No operations allowed after statement closed.
```

which is kind of obvious because the form frame is a singleton class and once the connection is closed it is not re-established (the constructor is not called).

the HomeScreen (home page of the app)

```
public class HomeScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static HomeScreen _instance;
/**
 * Creates new form HomeScreen
 */
private HomeScreen() {
    initComponents();
    showMessageOnAppClose();

    dbc = new DBConnection();
    dbc.init();
    dbConn = dbc.getMyConnection();
}

public static HomeScreen getInstance(){
    if (_instance == null){
        _instance = new HomeScreen();
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

the form:

```
public class StudentMemberRegist extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static StudentMemberRegist _instance;

/**
 * Creates new form StudentMemberRegist
 */
private StudentMemberRegist() {
    initComponents();
    Util.showMessageOnWindowClose(this);

    try {
        stmt = HomeScreen.dbConn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }

    setFormValues();
}

public static StudentMemberRegist getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new StudentMemberRegist();
    }

    return _instance;
}
```

the DBConnection class

```
public class DBConnection {
private Connection dbConnection;

/** Creates new instance of DBConnection */
public DBConnection(){

}

public void init(){

   try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LibManagement", "root", "ace");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed to get connection <class:DBConnection>");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getMyConnection() {
    return dbConnection;
}

public void close(Statement stmt) {

    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}

public void destroy() {

    if (dbConnection != null) {

        try {
            dbConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I am faced with the dilemma of never closing the database statement (stmt), or creating a public static Statement, using it throughout, and closing it when the application exits. Not closing the statement is probably not an option. Also, using a static statement, will be difficult to manage throughout. Help me out here!

Comment: ?? can't you create a new statement for each database operation?

Comment: yes, but i want to create  the statement when i launch the class and use it throughout, is there an efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a DB connection as an attribute in a singleton class. It's bad design. By definition, your singleton which is a GUI element shouldn't even be concerned about DB connections at all.

What you should do is have a CRUDManager class (for database create/read/update/delete) that can be called by your singleton. This would have 4 publics methods, as CRUD suggests. And it should handle it's own connections when needed (and close them when a transaction is finished, don't leave a connection open at application scope !). This should be transparent to the GUI.

Comment: No problem :) You can flag it as "resolved" though !